# I can not find the error that causes my array to get corrupted after running the case twice and exiting

Tags: c++

Hello everyone i am getting a `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'barray2' was corrupted.` this happens when i loop twice or more the same case and right when i decide to break the while loop with a e for exit. here is the sample of my code. do i have to clear the array when ever i am done? i try and add a barray[16]={0}; inside the case after it prints but i get a expression error, i got no clue :(

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num(0),k(0);
    int barray[16]={0};
    int num2(0),k2(0);
    int barray2[16]={0};
    int choice(2);
    int choice2;
    char option;


    while(choice != -1) 
    {


    cout << "enter a choice from B, O, or e(exit)" <<endl;
    cin >> option;

    if (option == 'B' || option == 'b')
    choice2 = 1;
    else if (option == 'O' || option == 'o')
    choice2 = 2;
    else if (option == 'e')
    choice2 = -1;
    else
    choice2 = 0;


    switch(choice2)
    {
    case 1:
    cout<<"please enter integer number to be converted to binary (lessthan 65536) "<<endl;
    cin>>num;

    while ((num !=0) && (k<=15))
    {
        barray[k]=num%2;
        num=num/2;
        k++;
    }

    for (k=15;k>=0;k--)
    {
        cout<<barray[k];
        if ((k%4)==0)
        cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    break;

    case 2:
    cout<<"please enter integer number to be converted to octal (lessthan 65536) "<<endl;
    cin>>num2;

    while ((num2 !=0) && (k2<=15))
    {
        barray2[k2]= num2 % 8;
        num2 = num2 / 8;
        k2++;
    }

    for (k2=15; k2>=0; k2--)
    {
        cout<<barray2[k2];
        if ((k2%4)==0)
        cout<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    break;
    case -1:
    cout << "you entered " << choice2 << endl;
    choice = -1;
    break;
    default:
    cout << "try again " << endl;



    }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not re-initialize your counters `k` and `k2`.

The loops quoted below leave `k` and `k2` set to -1 after they complete.  So, on the second pass of your `while` loop, you write to one index before the array:

```
for (k=15;k>=0;k--)
{
}

for (k2=15; k2>=0; k2--)
{
    //...
}
```

For clarity, I would initialize `k`/`k2` explicitly before each `while` loop that uses it:

```
k = 0;
while ((num !=0) && (k<=15))
{ 
    //...
}
```

(and likewise for the other loop with `k2`.)

Comment: i just found that error i changed it all and reset after each case run. thank you for looking it over